# can't download image from firebase storage to android local file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download image from firebase storage to android local storage.

below is the code i am using, for downloading the image.

**the variable dfile is the https download url**

```
    findViewById(R.id.download).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                final String dfile = sdownloadimg.getText().toString();
                StorageReference httpsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(dfile);

               // islandRef = storageRef.child("images/island.jpg");

                File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");

                httpsReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // Local temp file has been created
                        Toast.makeText(SellDetailActivity.this,"Success",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                        Toast.makeText(SellDetailActivity.this,"fail",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(SellDetailActivity.this,"try later",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

**The toast shows success msg, but nothing else happens.**

I had asked for permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: How do you know that no local file was created in the [default temp folder](https://www.quora.com/Where-should-I-find-temp-files-in-Android-mobiles)? Did you check the file system?

Comment: there was no img file in my gallery,or in cache of my app folder nor any downloading process gets shown on bar.I want the img to be saved on device ,so it can be viewed in gallery. Pls let me know how can i achieve it.

Comment: If the `onSuccess` runs, the file was written to a local file correctly. You might want to log `localFile.getAbsolutePath()` to see exactly where it was written.